# Native Android App: How to access app SQL file when it stored under context.getExternalFilesDir(null)

Tags: android, sql

I built an App that has undergone many revisions over the last years and now needs some more work.
However, I am finding that Android seems to have evolved extensively and rendered my app almost dead.

I had a basic App that stored details in a SQL file that was located :

```
context.getExternalFilesDir(null)
                    + File.separator + "myStuff"
                    + File.separator + DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
```

Previously I thought I used Device File Explorer in Android Studio to make backup copies of this SQL file but now it seems with Android Studio running my device Pixel 7 Pro API 34, that I cannot see these folders any more.

If I try and debug my app it states that the package is duplicated key are different and it wants to delete the old app to replace it with the new one. But I'm worried this will completely wipe out my SQL file.

Can any one tell me if permissions have changed and that this file is no longer accessible?
Is there any way of accessing this file in order to create a backup?

Any help would be appreciated.

Tried using Android Studio and Windows Explorer to search for this file but it seems like I no longer have access to it.

Comment: You should be able to see them with Android Studio Device File Explorer.